# prototype and methods - which one is preferred?

Tags: javascript

Why is using prototype for methods preferrable in js? When I create a new object for both, do they do the same thing?

```
function Rectangle(w, h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.area = function( ) { return this. width * this. height; }
}
```

or

```
Rectangle.prototype.area = function(){
    return this.width * this.height
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a big difference. Although both (as you've defined them) will give you the same return value when you call `.area()` on a `Rectangle` instance, in your first example, each and every `Rectangle` object gets its **own** copy of the `area` function. In the second case, they all share a single copy (which is more memory-efficient).

Which is preferred depends a great deal on the problem you're solving. In your example, almost certainly use the prototype. And that's usually the way you want to go. But if you have, say, a `Foo` constructor function and there will never be very many `Foo` instances **and** you think it's vitally important that `Foo` have truly private data, then you might use the [private members idiom](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html):

```
function Foo() {
    var trulyPrivateVariable;

    this.getVar = function() {
        return trulyPrivateVariable;
    };
    this.putVar = function(v) {
        // Presumably some logic or checks here
        trulyPrivateVariable = v;
    };
}
```

This pattern makes use of the fact that the functions are [closures](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) over the `trulyPrivateVariable` local variable in the constructor function.

Again, though, remember that those functions are *duplicated* for *every instance*, so this is only appropriate in moderation.

Worth noting that these are not mutually-exclusive. You can follow on the `Foo` above with:

```
Foo.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    // Do something completely unrelated -- note that code here
    // does not have access to `trulyPrivateVariable`, although it
    // will have access to `this.getVar()` and `this.putVar()`
    // (assuming it's called in the normal way).
};
```

...so that you get as much reuse as you can, by only putting the parts that absolutely need access to `trulyPrivateVariable` inside the constructor function where they'll get duplicated.

**Off-topic**: I've used anonymous functions (as you did) throughout above for brevity, but I'm [not a fan of them](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) in production code.

Comment: When you say -"In the second case, they all share a single copy (which is more memory-efficient)", does that mean the area is going to be same for all new objects of Rectangle?

Comment: @steve: No, of course not. :-) The function itself is shared, but the data on which it's operating (the `this` value) will be specific to each instance. So since `area` computes `this.width * this.height`, it will return the correct value for a given instance. At the risk of over-linking to my pathetically-anemic blog, you may find these other two posts helpful: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html and http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html

Comment: @steve: No worries. I clarified (I hope) the language in the opening paragraph of the answer.

Comment: yea, i had to think about it but your explanation makes sense now!  :)

Answer (score 1):

using prototype is preferable.  It is a more efficient way for JS to store which methods are available to a "class".  You should look at some tutorials on object oriented javascript, and on prototypal inheritance.